# Changing the font size of the Texmaker's buttons

Tags: texmaker, updating

Some year ago I changed the font size of the Texmaker's interface; today I installed the new version, but I forgot how to reduce the font size of the interface (not of the editor).
I searched a setting to do it in the configuration file texmaker.ini, but without any success.

Could you tell me how to do it?

---

EDIT: I'm using Windows 10 (64 bit).

[image]

[image]

Comment: For me texmaker has a "Change Interface Font" menu item under "Options", which allows you to specify the size. That'll just change the font size in menus though, but it sounds like you actually might want to change the toolbar icon image size too? (I don't think those are done with a font.) Not sure, but it might be possible to change the default icon size for all Qt apps on your operating system, but it might help to know which one you're using.

Comment: Hello @frabjous thank you for your comment. Could you post a screenshot please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want me to post a screenshot of. The menu item is not hard to find – [here's an image of it](https://imgur.com/a/mWQmYzq) – but you may be using a different version. I'm using 5.0.4 at the moment, but it's there on 5.1.3 which I have on another computer as well.

Comment: Hi @frabjous in my menu there isn't the item "Change Interface Font", see the edit please.

Comment: What version are you using? On what OS?

Comment: @frabjous Windows 10 (64 bit), Texmaker 5.1.3

Comment: I'm on Linux. The corresponding entries in texmaker.ini look like his `X11\Font%20Family=Sans Serif`
and `X11\Font%20Size=10`, but "X11" is the display server for Linux so I doubt it's the same on Windows. Maybe another WIndows user can help.